# Permission issue in Document Library - Read Only user is able to edit and save document

Tags: document-library, permissions, version-history

Scenario:

---

I am logged in as a site owner of a SharePoint 2010 site with full permission on a Document Library. I have a test account that has only Read and Limited Access permission to this Document Library. I open Firefox with the test user account. Then I log into the SharePoint site with the test user; open one of the Word documents in the library; edit and save it.

Problem:

---

The document is not supposed to save! The test user has only Read/ Limited Access permission. Additionally, when I log in as myself and look at the Version history, the document is saved as a major version - Modified by: ME!

---

I have already cleared the cache; even restarted my computer. The problem still persists. Is this an expected behavior because I am logged into the computer/domain as myself? Any suggestions or documentation confirming the latter would be greately appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is the test user in the Site Collection Administrators by any chance?

Comment: Nope. I checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the document with Word, then you are not likely opening the document with the credentials used by Firefox. If word is not prompting you to enter credentials when opening the file, then it is most likely using your windows credentials.

In order to properly test this sort of thing, I generally try to logon to windows as the user I want to test.

Comment: I agree. If you switch users in the browser, then open a file with an Office application, your local windows credentials are used to manipulate that file. For true testing as the other user, you must log on to the domain with the test account, not just switch SharePoint users.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen and it's usually credentials haven't been fully flushed. It might show I'm logged in as the other user, but if I navigate to another page it will revert back to my normal account.

When I'm testing permissions and need separate accounts I alwyas use separate browsers.

Comment: Thaks for your suggestion. I took this point into consideration and logged in as the test user in a completely differnt browser, i.e., Firefox while I was logged in as myself in IE. This still is an issue. Also, I have restarted the computer and done this; so credential flush should not have been an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Access on the file. With SharePoint Online, some user might share the file with other users. Delete those shares will solve issues like this.